# c++: why the last output is not an address and how to get the value 9?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a[3][4]={{4,8,13,9},{1,6,9,3},{0,2,7,10}};

    cout<< (a+1)<<endl;
    cout<<*(a+1)<<endl;
    cout<<(*(a+1)+2)<<endl;
    cout<< *(*(a+1)+2);
    return 0;
}
```

My output is

```
0x23fe30
0x23fe30
0x23fe38
9
```

Comment: `*(*(a+1)+2)` is equivalent to `a[1][2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember How `2D array` equivalent `pointer` notation is, for e.g
If you have `2D array` like `char arr[row][col]` then to access each element you would be doing `arr[row][col]` and

```
arr[row][col] == *(*(arr + row ) + col)
```

In your case `row = 1` and `col = 2` then find what `a[1][2]` will be ? its `9`.